# Bootstrap button not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my bootstrap panel in my panel-head area, I have a button so can click on form `<button type="submit" form="form-user-group" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>`

In the button I use form="form-user-group" and then on the form I have id `<form id="form-user-group"></form>`

**It lets me submit form fine on fire fox and Google Chrome But I have issue with Internet Explorer will not work wont pick up form="form-user-group**"

If I have button in side the form it works on IE but not when I have it out side of the form. How can I fix it so it works on IE out side of form.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
<div class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px"><h1 class="panel-title"><?php echo $title;?></h1></div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/users_group');?>" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
<button type="submit" form="form-user-group" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<form action="<?php echo base_url('admin/users_group/add'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-user-group" class="form-horizontal">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot keep the submit button **outside** the `<form>` tag as the id you specified is not how the form finds the button but it looks for a button **within** it's tag.

Read here for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1

However, you can use JavaScript or it's library, jQuery to link the button to the form instead of trying to link the form to the button. You can try something like this:

```
$('#formButton').click(function() {
    $('#form-user-group').submit();
});
```

where, `#formButton` is the id of the button you want to use for submitting the form `#form-user-group`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice tried your method not work but then tried onclick and worked fine shown in my Answer

Answer (score 1):

I have found out now that with internet explorer if you wish to do form submit button out side of the form you best to use onclick for with javascript

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submit()">Save</button>

<form id="form-something" method="post" action="">

</form>

<script>
function submit() {
// for IE fix
    $("form[id*='form-']").submit();
}
</script>
```